Как удалить устаревшие текстовые файлы через план обслуживания
Создал план обслуживания по копированию баз данных, так же в план добавил задачи "Очистка после обслуживания", в этих задачах удаляются бэкапы, которые старше 2-х месяцев, и должны удаляться текстовые отчеты плана обслуживания, но они, почему-то, ни в какую не удаляются. Пробовал создать отдельный план с задачами "Очистка после обслуживания" (удалять текстовые файлы плана) и "Очистка журнала", запускал этот план обслуживания вручную - текстовые файлы как были на месте так и остались. Файлы лежат в директории "E:\MS_SQL_BACKUP". Пробовал включать/отключать "Включить вложенные папки первого уровня" - так же без результата. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить очистку текстовых файлов?

Ну вы хотя бы СУБД указали, что ли... про версию и используемое клиентское ПО даже не заикаюсь.

Microsoft SQL Server 2019, Microsoft SQL Server Tools 18 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
